# How do I get back to normal log in after hibernating in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, gnome, login, hibernate

After using the command `sudo systemctl hibernate` to hibernate my laptop running Ubuntu 18.04, the login screen changes design and some applications I installed went missing.

I restarted the computer but still no luck. Attached is the image of how the login screen looks like.

[image: login screen photo]

Comment: Can you still log in there? This design looks ancient. That together with you saying that some applications are gone, could it be that there was an older version of Ubuntu installed in parallel on your disk and it now booted into that instead of 18.04?

Comment: Yes I could still log in from there. There was no older version of Ubuntu installed before. This is the first time. After logging in even video plays very slow.

Comment: I'll recommend to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm` and select GDM greeter from the list of possible alternatives.